# What tools do you use in order to easily navigate complex javascript frameworks source code?

Tags: javascript, atom.io

How does one quickly jump between different API functions from different files or modules in a modern JavaScript framework?

I'm specifically interested in doing this with ReactJS using Atom, but any answer that makes me understand how one does this with any other editors and frameworks is helpful.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by “quickly jump between”? Do you mean opening source files for a function being called? For documentation?

Comment: Imagine having the angular, or the reactjs framework code in its intimidating wholeness on your computer. How do you go about understanding the source code? Do you open a file and then search for the function calls in all other files? Or do you employ a toolset (ctags, or something different) that allows you to do the jumps, from call to defintion automatically?